# node.js limit number of requests from a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, busboy

I'm building an app in node.js that allows users to upload documents using express and busboy. The user can upload multiple documents in one upload but is limited to a total file size of 20mb.

Is it possible to prevent a user from making multiple upload requests in a given amount of time? My concern is that someone could easily write a script to upload 20mb (the limit per upload) and repeat this 100x a minute or some large amount. It would be ideal to have a user only be able to upload once every 30 seconds or minute.

Comment: I believe you ultimately want some kind of [rate-limiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting)...

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to rate-limit by IP, this module adds various configurations including the ability to apply the rule by path (example your upload function):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest [rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible) package

```
const { RateLimiterMemory } = require('rate-limiter- 
flexible');

const rateLimiter = new RateLimiterMemory(
{
  points: 1,
  duration: 30, // per 30 seconds
});

const rateLimiterMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const userId = getUserId();
  // Consume 1 point for each action
  rateLimiter.consume(userId) // or req.ip
    .then(() => {
      next();
    })
    .catch((rejRes) => {
      res.status(429).send('Too Many Requests');
    });
};

app.use('/upload', rateLimiterMiddleware);
```

`Memory` works in current process memory only. There are also `Cluster`, `Mongo` and `Redis` limiters for cluster and distributed apps

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this in a number of ways, but I think probably the approach that makes the most sense to me is to have either a total upload limit per user, or some sort of date field that indicates when a specific user could upload a new set of files.

If you could provide some more details about your stack, I could probably help bang some code out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware to check it

1. `app.use('/upload', upload-middleware, req-res-func)`
2. `upload-middleware` receive `req`, calc user by cookies/session-id/etc and stored last upload time. If current request time and prev time is match then call `next()` to forwarding request to req-res-function else call `next(new Error('Upload error...'))`.